# visual studio help Visual Basic in the Weekday function?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2019

visual studio help

I have a question about the function: Weekday
I want to appear today only in the form through the: Label
I tried here but it didn't work:
Dim dn As Integer
dn = Weekday(Of Date)()

```
    If dn = 1 Then
        Label61.Text = "Saturday"
    End If
    If dn = 2 Then
        Label61.Text = "Sunday"
    End If
    If dn = 3 Then
        Label61.Text = "Monday"
    End If
    If dn = 4 Then
        Label61.Text = "Tuesday"
    End If
    If dn = 5 Then
        Label61.Text = "Wednesday"
    End If
    If dn = 6 Then
        Label61.Text = "Thursday"
    End If
    If dn = 7 Then
        Label61.Text = "Friday"
    End If
```

It appears to me that there is an error in the line:
Weekday(Of Date)()
in : Of dy
Please find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DayOfWeek` Enum to get week days, Use `Today.DayOfWeek` to get the week number. If you want to get the week day you can use ToSting method i.e. `Today.DayOfWeek.ToString()`

Comment: Well thank you my dear brother
The task was completed successfully, as you were told
Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for the update.. if your issue is resolved please mark the answer as accepted..